# The extension name X is not registered - why looking in AppData\Local\Temp?

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I have a custom wcf behaviour used by a dynamic send port. This work fine on my Dev VM and a Test VM.

I have been careful to ensure the configuration for the component has been added to the system.serviceModel\extensions\behaviorExtensions element of the 64bit machine.config file - this is added by the BizTalk deployment framework.

My problem is that with the next test VM, the following is being created in the event log:

> Error Description:
>
> Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Converters.CreateBehaviorException: Unable to create endpoint behavior configuration element from XML configuration.
> Check the following:
> 1. Verify behavior element extensions in machine.config are correctly configured.
> 2. Restart the application if machine.config was recently updated.
> 3. Ensure the configuration is valid XML that conforms to the configuration schema.
> Configuration:  ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Invalid element in configuration. The extension name 'biztalkAddHttpHeader' is not registered in the collection at system.serviceModel/extensions/behaviorExtensions.  (C:\Users\svc_stebt_src\AppData\Local\Temp\Config\d6d5cc4c-3150-4d02-8c7b-95be03db0d9e.config line 12)

I have tried rebooting the server.

The file mentioned in the error does not exist: C:\Users\svc_stebt_src\AppData\Local\Temp\Config\d6d5cc4c-3150-4d02-8c7b-95be03db0d9e.config

Any ideas?

Following the comment from @Hichamveo, I followed this post to add the extension config directly for the WCF-Custom adapter: [Toon's blog](https://www.codit.eu/blog/2012/12/14/how-to-register-wcf-extensions-in-biztalk/)

If I configure a static send port - the extension is available:

[image]

However, when sending through the dynamic send port, I still get the same exception in the event log

Comment: The host instance handler used on your send port is 32 or 64? Try to add the behavior config to 32 machine.config and also delete your temporary files. Make sur that your dll is present in the gac

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but yes It is 64bit and it is GAC’d

Comment: Try to add your behavior on the host level

Comment: Sorry @Hichamveo I don’t understand, could you please elaborate?

Comment: You have also a possibility to declare/config your behavior extension on the host or host instance (don't remember which one exactly) properties by adding a small file.config containing only the behavior declaration

Comment: Also have a look on this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/23ce805e-fca5-4314-b6ca-af54314b8618/webhttp-is-not-registered-in-the-collection-at-systemservicemodelextensionsbehaviorextensions?forum=wcf

Answer (score 0):

Please check that indeed you are using 64-bit host

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2015/09/08/dynamic-send-port-is-sending-message-using-the-wrong-host/